# How to use more than one button in Java android studio to retrieve a database from firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried using **Recyclerview adapter** technique to retrieve data as list of row in a main activity, I don't need toast because I need to retrieve a list of data to be shown on a main page after button click.

The problem it's only works for one single button, my plan was to use more than one button and each button to retrieve a specific query from same firebase database using Java code (android studio) any ideas would be helpful ? thank you

1. connection between main page (android and firebase) was successful.
2. established connection with single query with one button to retrieve firebase database, data retrieved successfully using recyclerview.
3. the result was successful as a row of data in a main.
4. when I click the button it works fine.
5. I have created other buttons and copied code in a main activity but it did not work.

MainAcitvity
MedicsAdapter
MedicsActivity
Medic

shows blank page after adding other buttons, no result.
this file is the Medics activity :

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("profiles").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
```

if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

```
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();

                        for(DocumentSnapshot d : list){

                            Medic p = d.toObject(Medic.class);
                            MedicList.add(p);

                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
```

and below from main activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_save:
            saveProduct();
            break;
        case R.id.textview_view_medics:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MedicsActivity.class));
            break;

        case R.id.imageView:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MedicsActivity.class));
            break;


        case R.id.imageView2:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MedicsActivity.class));
            break;
    }

}
```

[another button imageView2 , I am using same adapter.]

Comment: show us some code. also what did you copy in java file. does the new button correspond to new code or old code?

Comment: the old code is working but i can not add any new button to respond and retrieve specific data from firebase database

Answer (score 0):

I am posting answer for the question I asked earlier and I hope someone could benefit from it:

You must create new activity for each button you are dedicating to pull data from Firebase database, for example if your button_1 views data from Firebase database then once you have added another button e.g. button_2 that button must refer to new activity created, the good part you don't need to create new file adapters or activity layout, only you need to create a MedicsActivity: 
button_1 ... > MedicsActivity.java   and activity_medics.xml
button_2 ... > MedicsAcitivity 2.java and activity_medics2.xml

```
 case R.id.imageView2:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MedicsActivity2.class));
        break;
```